Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.example.chess/files/stockfish-arm64-v8a": error=13, Permission denied
I am new to android and trying to build an android app chess with stockfish. I downloaded the binary of stockfish and trying to execute it but it fails with the error
Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.example.chess/files/stockfish-arm64-v8a": error=13, Permission denied

This is the code where I am trying to copy binary from assets to file directory mentioned above and execute it
        String abi = getAbi();
        String stockfishName = "stockfish-" + abi;

        File stockfishFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), stockfishName);
        Log.d(TAG, "Stockfish file path: " + stockfishFile.getAbsolutePath());

        if (!stockfishFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stockfish file does not exist. Copying from assets...");
            copyStockfishFromAssets(stockfishName);
        }

        logFileDetails(stockfishFile);

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Stockfish process...");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(stockfishFile.getAbsolutePath());
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            process = pb.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Stockfish process started successfully");


Code for copyStockfishFromAssets
 private void copyStockfishFromAssets(String stockfishName) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Copying Stockfish from assets: " + stockfishName);
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(stockfishName);
        File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), stockfishName);

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Stockfish copied successfully. Setting executable permission...");
        if (!outputFile.setExecutable(true, true)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set executable permission programmatically");
        }
    }

Can anyone tell me how to execute this binary
NOTE: I am very new to android so a working code or some direction to it would be very helpful
